# NextAuth and MongoDB - need user information in session

Tags: next.js, next-auth, next.js13

I have the problem that netxuath does not return my session with token etc. In the configuration I explicitly specified session: jwt and use Mongodb as the adapter. If I log in with Google, everything works, DB is filled (session, users, accounts) and I get a session back, see picture, but not the one I need. Email, username, token, etc. What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

```
 export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {

 adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),

 providers: [
   GoogleProvider({
   clientId: `${process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}`,
   clientSecret: `${process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET}`,
   authorization: {
     params: {
       prompt: "consent",
       access_type: "offline",
       response_type: "code",
     },
   },
 }),
],

callbacks: {
 async session({ session, user, token }) {
   if (session) {
     session.user = token;
   }
   return session;
 },

 async jwt({ token, user, account }) {
   if (account) {
     token.id = user.id;
   }
   return token;
  },
},

session: {
  stragety: "jwt",
  },
};
```

the result in the debugger if i print it out:

```
if (session) {console.log(JSON.stringify(session));
```

[image]